# Yellowstone Geyser GRPC Error FailedtoLoadPlugin

Tags: rpc, solana-test-validator, geyser, private-node

When launching my validator (self hosted, working for more than a month and updated to a plugin matching version (1.17.20)) the validator first load then return an error.
The plugin is https://github.com/rpcpool/yellowstone-grpc/ for version 1.17.20 was downloaded from the release page.

command:

```
solana-validator --geyser-plugin-config yellowstone-grpc-geyser/config.json [end of the command]
```

logs:

```
INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_service] Starting GeyserPluginService from config files: ["yellowstone-grpc-geyser/config.json"]
ERROR solana_validator] Failed to start validator: "Failed to load the Geyser plugin: FailedToLoadPlugin(Error { code: InvalidRequest, message: \"Failed to load plugin: Cannot load plugin shared library\", data: None })"
```

config.json

```
{
    "libpath": "/home/solana/bin/yellowstone-grpc-geyser/yellowstone-grpc-geyser-release/lib/libyellowstone_grpc_geyser.so",
    "log": {
        "level": "info"
    },
    "grpc": {
        "address": "0.0.0.0:10000",
        "max_decoding_message_size": "4_194_304",
        "snapshot_plugin_channel_capacity": null,
        "snapshot_client_channel_capacity": "10_000_000",
        "channel_capacity": "100_000",
        "unary_concurrency_limit": 100,
        "unary_disabled": false
    },
    "block_fail_action": "log"
}
```

Any idea about the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error is thrown here: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/377e1f911294395b666dfa799e30a25f8aefeb9b/geyser-plugin-manager/src/geyser_plugin_manager.rs#L121

And it comes specifically from here: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/377e1f911294395b666dfa799e30a25f8aefeb9b/geyser-plugin-manager/src/geyser_plugin_manager.rs#L392

So likely, there's something wrong with `libyellowstone_grpc_geyser.so` -- either it's the wrong version or it's in the wrong directory.